# How to convert a 2d numpy array to a picture?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have not found a solution for this anywhere; I found many solutions where I can visualize an array by a picture of different colors;

However, I want something different: If I have an array, let's make it simple and I have

```
a=np.ones([3,3])
```

Then I want to export this matrix to a jpeg or png where the numpy array looks like a nice matrix from a paper or book, i.e. as it is written on LaTeX; so something you would get when compiling the command in LaTeX:

```
$a=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\\ 1 & 1 & 1  \\\ \end{pmatrix}$
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Translation from a matrix into the expected latex command looks like a straightforward procedure. What seems to be a problem?

Comment: I thought that there is a way to directly get a picture of the matrix - I mean it does not need to look exactly like in LaTeX but I just wanted to give an idea of how it should look like approximately as for big matrices, the translation would get very tedious

Answer (score 1):

You could use Matplotlib to plot your array as a table with [`plt.table`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html). See the linked docs for options like `colLabels` for the column headers. Also, you'll probably want to modify the figure or the axes to adjust your image. For the following example, I have only turned off the axes with `plt.axis("off")`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (5, 3))
plt.axis("off")
plt.table(cellText=data, colLabels=["A", "B", "C"], loc="center")
plt.savefig("data.png")
```

[image: plot]